# Is it an example of a Monad? If not, why?

Tags: swift, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to study functional programming applied to Swift (a multi-paradigm language). One of the exercises I proposed to myself was trying to do a declarative Poker Hand evaluator.

Here are some code excerpts and my question at the end:

```
typealias Rule = ([Card]) -> Result
```

Where Result is a type that holds the current evaluation state (cards already evaluated on a rank, remaining cards, if the last rule evaluation was successful or not and the evaluated ranks). The input is an array (could be a set of) cards to be evaluated.

I also created this function:

```
func id(_ hand:[Card]) -> Result ...
```

That creates a mininum Result from a card set.

Result also have a set of functions to chain rule evaluations (simplified here):

```
func apply(_ rule:Rule) -> Result
func andThen(_ rule:Rule) -> Result
func andAlso(_ rule:Rule) -> Result
func otherwise(_ rule:Rule) -> Result
func continueWith(_ rule:Rule) -> Result
```

Whats allowed me to declare the poker rank rules as:

```
let fullHouse = { (hand) in
   threeOfAKind(hand).andThen(pair)
}
```

or

```
let royalStraightFlush = { (hand)  in
  straightFlush(hand).andAlso(straightAceHigh)
}
```

and chaining all rank rules as:

```
let evaluate = { (hand) in
//id(hand)
    royalStraightFlush(hand)
    .otherwise(straightFlush)
    .otherwise(fourOfAKind)
    .otherwise(fullHouse)
    .otherwise(flush)
    .otherwise(straight)
    .otherwise(threeOfAKind)
    .otherwise(twoPair)
    .otherwise(pair)
    .continueWith(highCard) }
```

`Result`, as it is:

- Encompasses a type ([Card]) into a broader context (R a)
- Has an id (result) function that put an object of type a into a minimum "result" context (a -> R a)

But...

- It has not just one generic >>= bind function, but several specific ones, that takes R a -> (a -> R a) -> R a that could chain rules and get the card set to be evaluated from the previous partial result state.
- It is not (as it is implemented) generic enough to handle other types instead of Card or [Card]. In the other hand I think the same chaining logic could be used on other rule systems with some changes...

My question is: is `Result` a monad? Otherwise, why it is not? My two concerns are those presented above.

I think understanding these points (or knowing that are some other blind spots) on this concrete example will clarify a little bit the monad concept to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Monads are built around type *constructors*, not types. In Haskell, for example, `[Int]` is not a monad, but `[]` is, since you can define `return :: a -> [a]` and `(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]`. So strictly speaking, `Result` is probably not a monad.

Comment: What does `Result` implement other than a boolean result of applying a rule? Note that your `fullHouse` rule doesn't indicate how it would handle the requirement that the three-of-a-kind and the pair cannot overlap.

Comment: Thanks! It keeps two extra information: a subset of cards not yet evaluated (ex: the two remaining cards of the three-of-a-kind rule, hat could or could not be a pair) and the ranks found (ex: a three-of-a-kind, a higher card and another higher card that could be used to compare hands). There is also a boolean to chain the rules...

Comment: OK, then I imagine something like `type Result v = State HandInfo v` and `andThen :: Rule -> Bool -> ResultBool`, so that  `fullHouse h = threeOfAKind h >>= andThen pair` and `evaluate h = royalFlush >>= otherwise straightFlush >>= ... >>= otherwise pair >>= otherwise highCard`. `andThen`, `otherWise`, et al. aren't binding functions so much as factories to create functions to bind with `>>=`.

Comment: I think I dind't get this last one , chepner...

Comment: It's a too-terse example of how you might adapt `Result` from a type to a type constructor in Haskell, and how it might subsequently be used as a monad. I don't know enough Swift to suggest anything comparable in that language.

Answer (score 0):

Monads have to obey the three Monad Laws:

- Left identity:  `return a >>= f ≡ f a`
- Right identity: `m >>= return ≡ m`
- Associativity:  `(m >>= f) >>= g ≡ m >>= (\x -> f x >>= g)`

This also implies the implementation of `return` (or equivalent) and `>>=` (variously called bind, flatmap, etc.) for your monad..  Haskell (and other languages) also adds the map function (`>>`) even though it can be implemented in terms of `>>=`.

In addition, as @chepner points out, monads are abstractions that are not concrete types in themselves.  They are generic and can only be instantiated via a type constructor.  `List` is a monad but you cannot instantiate a `List`.  You can, however, instantiate a `List[Int]`.

If you want to get a good conceptual picture of what makes a monad a monad, take a look at Brian Beckman's video [Don't Fear the Monad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8&feature=kp).  Also, there is a good series of blog posts, [Monads are Elephants](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2007/09/monads-are-elephants-part-1.html).